# Pull up and down resistors at the same time

Tags: resistors, i2c, pullup, pulldown

I have an I2C circuit with a 4.7 kohm pull-up resistor for each line. I think it might be a too strong (too small in value) resistor and the data isn't read properly. The processor I'm using has the option to set a pull up/down on the pins so I want to try to pull down the lines. What will the pull value be? Is it the absolute value of the difference? Will it short out?

[image]

[image]

[image: I2C clock, every square up is 3v]

[image: I2C data, every square up is 3v]

[image: That is how the clock looks up close]

[image: The bus on the circuit]

Comment: Why do you think it might be too strong - have you calculated a resistor current that exceeds a connected device's sink capability (unlikely) or made some oscilloscope measurements that somehow lead you to this conclusion? Connecting a pulldown forms a voltage divider with your bus in the middle, almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: I looked at the scope and saw the signal reaches 3v3 but not fully reaching GND(reaching about 1v1)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a picture of the scope trace. Your logical process seems reasonable, but based on experience, 4.7 k would not be too strong, so I suspect there is something else going on. I encourage you to try other values and see what happens, though. That could lead us to guess what is really going on.

Answer (score 5):

The pull down value depends on your MCU and it reads in the data sheet. Open the data sheet and find the value. It might be tens of kilo-ohms.

However it will likely change nothing. Pulling down internally is weak compared to external reaistor and it will only make the idle bus voltage lower. The impedance change is so low will likely make no difference.

4k7 is not too strong for standard I2C compliant devices. It might even be too weak in some cases. Likely the problem is elsewhere, maybe in the software.

Based on your added info that low voltage only goes down to one volt indicates something is driving the bus with push pull output while all devices must be open drain. Likely MCU software problem configuring the IO pins incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
The datasheet says it is 40k so that's pretty weak. When I look at the signal on the scope it reaches 3v3 on top but doesn't get to GND(gets to about 1v).

Comment: @EyalPorat, that sounds like some other device is actively driving the line high when it ought to be in high-Z state. Some programmable device (microcontroller or FPGA for example) is the most likely culprit. An additional 40k pull-down will not fix this. The more of your schematic and BOM that you can share, the better chance we have to be able to help you.

Comment: added the sch, Thanks!

Comment: Also, what is a culprit?

Comment: **culprit**
/ˈkʌlprɪt/
*noun*
1. a person who is responsible for a crime or other misdeed.
2. the cause of a problem or defect.

Comment: I think justme's hypothesis is a good one. To test it, add a 47k pulldown. If no other chip is messing with the bus, this will form a voltage divider with the 4k7 pullup, and the high level on your I2C bus will be 3.0V instead of 3.3V. It should still work. If a chip is driving the bus high, then you will still see a 3.3V high level. Once this test is done, you should of course remove the pulldown.

Comment: After looking at the scope trace, I agree that probably some device on the bus is trying to drive the signals high, and that is why it never gets near GND.

Comment: The bus is not reaching 3.3V either way(when it is just pulled up, voltage devided or aditionally pulled up)

Comment: The waveform looks extremely bad. Zoom in to 1V or 500mV per div, and make sure you are using 10x probe mode, **do not use 1x probe**.

Comment: What does the x means?

Comment: @EyalPorat Look at your probe. If it has a switch labeled 1x and 10x, switch it to 10x. If not, figure out which type of probe it is.

Comment: I believe it is a 1x probe but I don't really have a way to know. why should I use the 10x probe?

Comment: If the low going edge looks like shark fin, it might mean there is a problem and the signal is really garbage, or signal is OK but low bandwidth 1x probe is used so it is a measurement error. Always use 10x probe unless you know what you are doing. Also, what I2C clock frequency is that?

Comment: I also wonder about your grounding: both of the PCB/circuit itself and your probe connection. Where and how are you grounding your scope probe and are you sure you have a good common ground between the MCU, IMU and PSU? (Also agree about the 10x probe...)

Comment: The probe is grounded to the ST-link as well as the ST-link and the circuit. the I2C frq it 100khz. I do not have a 10x probe at the moment...

Comment: It might be the scope problem. when I put the scope on 1V per div it seems the I2C line is moving between 3V3 and 3V. It is not a very quality oscilloscope.